# Selecting where an entity contains a list thats a subset of another list

Tags: jpa, jpql

I am writing a JPQL query and i have the following scenario.  I have a Question entity which contains a list of Tags. I would like to select all Questions that contains a given List of tags. How do i do this with JPA?

I would like to do something like SELECT x FROM Question x WHERE x.tags 'contains all' :tags

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[This searches for ANY not ALL; please refer other correct answers.]

You can set list as a parameter.

```
SELECT x FROM Question x WHERE x.tags IN :tags
```

Also try using (:tags), as it depends on the JPA implementation you are using.

Comment: I will test this in a short while. I know it works if am checking if one tag is in a list of tags. But now my situation involves testing if a list of tags is a subset of another list of tags.

Comment: Does not work. It returnes a 'Question' where ':tags' contain any element in 'x.tags'.

Comment: This doesn't work, didn't even pass sql prepare check.

Answer (score 5):

Try like this:

```
select distinct q from Question q join q.tags as t 
where t.name in (:tags) 
group by q.id, q.author, q.title, q.content,q.postedAt 
having count(t.id) = :size
```

Comment: This answer worked for me using MySQL. @nayan-wadekar answer was giving sql grammar exceptions.

Answer (score 4):

[Nayans](https://stackoverflow.com/users/366964/nayan-wadekar) solution does'nt work for me. Its selecting every 'x' which matches the first (or any?) entry of the given collection ':tags'. If this really worked for you, you should test you application again ;) might be JPA dependend - I don't know.
 Tip: Try [Krzysztofs](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1093978/krzysztof-kaczmarek) solution or use mine:

```
SELECT x FROM Question x 
WHERE x IN (
    SELECT y FROM Question y
    INNER JOIN y.tags yt
    WHERE yt IN (
        :tags
    )
    GROUP BY y
    HAVING COUNT( DISTINCT yt) = (
        :tagsSize // should be clear ;)
    )
)
```

Comment: Can't the tagsize check be fooled by you requiring two tags. and the question having two but only matching one?