# binding variables in an EJB query IN clause

Tags: sql, oracle, ejb-3.0, bind-variables

Is it possible to bind a list in an EJB IN clause like this?

```
Query query = myEntitymanager.createNativeQuery("SELECT e FROM EntityName e WHERE e.id IN (:ids)");
//ids is a List of Long
query.setParameter("ids", ids);
result = query.getResultSet();
```

Comment: Why don't you try it & post the question in case of problem. Similar one, can refer http://stackoverflow.com/a/4644668/366964

Answer (score 0):

**IN** clause works in JQPL, here http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/bnbuf.html#bnbvf you can read about it on javaee 6 specification. 
But what do you wanna do?
In your example you are building a native query so IN clause support and behavior depends on wich jdbc driver you are using.