# Find all items which contain certain set elements with JPA QL

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, jpql

I have an `Item` class which contains a `Set` of `Tag` objects. Now I want to find all Items which contain *all* the required the tags with JPA (based on Hibernate 4.1.9).

My repository methods gets a java.util.Set and the body of this method looks like this:

```
entityManager.createQuery("select item from Item as item where item.tags in :tags")
.setParameter("tags", tags)
.getResultList()
```

It looks like this [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4644668/238134) to me, but all I get is the error message:

> IllegalArgumentException: org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException: unexpected end of subtree [select item from models.Item as item where item.tags in ()]

If I turn the condition around

```
"select item from Item as item where :tags in item.tags"
```

what I think would be correct (instead of the above query), I get a `NullPointerException` in the last line (`getResultList()`).

What is wrong?

Comment: If I express it without `in` the exceptions are not thrown. So it seems to be a pure JPQL problem. I posted another [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14340156/).

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your `tags` collection is empty, or perhaps even null, which is known to lead to this error (for one example, see [this blog](http://parasjain.net/2008/12/09/hibernate-error-orghibernatehqlastquerysyntaxexception-unexpected-end-of-subtree/)).  This generates the query you see in the error:

```
select item from models.Item as item where item.tags in ()
```

Which, if sent to the database, would likely result in a error (for instance, `ERROR 1064 (42000)`, in MySQL, a syntax error).

You'll need to validate that `tags` is non-empty before adding it as a parameter to the query.

Comment: `tags` is not empty and contains the expected objects. Any other idea?

Comment: Hang on, `select item from Item as item where item.tags in :tags` am i to take it that a single `item` may have multiple `tags`?  As in, `WHILE 'list of tags' IN 'another list of tags'`?  IN generally looks more like `WHILE 'single value (per record)' IN 'list of values'`.  To be honest, I'm not really certain what, exactly, that would mean, but it certainly isn't supported by SQL.  If Hibernate implements some special logic to support it, I would find it a bit surprising.