# Finding items with a set containing all elements of a given set with jpql

Tags: java, sql, hibernate, jpa, jpql

I want to find the items that contain *all* the given tags in their tags set.

Here are the simplified classes:

```
@Entity   
class Item {
  @ManyToMany
  var tags: java.util.Set[Tag] = new java.util.HashSet[Tag]()
}

@Entity
class Tag {
  @ManyToMany(mappedBy="tags")
  var items: java.util.Set[Item] = new java.util.HashSet[Item]
}
```

If I try it like this

```
select distinct i 
from Item i join i.tags t
where t in (:tags)
```

I get the items that contain *any* of the given tags. That is not surprising, but I want Items that contain *all* of the given tags. So I try it the other way around:

```
select distinct i 
from Item i join i.tags t
where (:tags) in t
```

I get the error message `org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: arguments of row IN must all be row expressions`. It works if `tags` contains only a single tag, but it fails with more than that.

How can I express this in JPQL?

Comment: Because I think you can't compare set with other array in hibernate. I think you must rewrite you sql query code.

Comment: Query query = session.createQuery("from Stock where stockId in (:code)");
query.setParameterList("code", idList);

Comment: I appreciate that you showed in your question how you get the items that contain any of the given tags! This's what I was looking for. I can confirm it works with `@ElementCollection`s too.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

The trick is to use a count:

```
select i from Item i join i.tags t
where t in :tags group by i.id having count(i.id) = :tagCount
```

Comment: This is one of those things that takes you forever to see it, and then when you do, you can't believe you didn't see it all along

Answer (score 4):

I just had the same problem as you. I used the reductio ad absurdum:

```
select distinct i from Item i where i not in (select i2 from Item i2 join i2.tags t where t not in :tags)
```

Comment: I like this method since I already had a query that returned what I didn't want, but I was going to need to add several conditions to the inner select in order for the sub query results to remain small.  Instead I used a count method described here http://stackoverflow.com/a/21645545/429896 that doesn't require adding stuff after "group by".

Comment: This failed for me when `Item` would contain elements without any tags.

Comment: this is not matching all given - but only single. The subselects in will match if not in - and not "not in all of them". you just covered the initial problem into 2 not not solving it.

Comment: this is equivalent to "select distinct i from Item i where i in (..tags)" and thus not matching only those containing ALL given tags.