# JPA Query on @OneToMany Set<Entity>

Tags: java, jpa

The GenericVehicle represent a vehicle which may have 0 or more GenericVehicleAccessory.

```
@Entity
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.JOINED)
public class GenericVehicle extends GenericEntity {

@Id
private Long id;

@Column(nullable=false)
@NotNull(message="{GenericVehicle.vehicleName.notNull")
@Size(max=128, message="{GenericVehicle.vehicleName.size")
private String vehicleName;

@OneToMany(mappedBy = "genericVehicle", cascade = { CascadeType.ALL }, orphanRemoval = true, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
private Set<GenericVehicleAccessory> accessories;
// .. 
}


@Entity
@Table(name = "GENERICVEHICLEACCESSORIES")
public class GenericVehicleAccessory extends GenericEntity {

@Id
private long id;

@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinColumn(name = "GENERICVEHICLE_ID")
private GenericVehicle genericVehicle;

private String name;

// ..
}
```

I would like to perform a query which selects all GenericVehicle(s) which owns a Set (accessories) of a given criteria set.

For example:

```
+----+-------------------+
| ID | VEHICLENAME       |
+----+-------------------+
|  1 | Toyota Auris      |
|  2 | Volkswagen Passat |
|  3 | Bentley Arnage    |
|  4 | Hyundai Accent    |
|  5 | Toyota Auris      |
+----+-------------------+
+-------------------+----------------------------------+
| GENERICVEHICLE_ID | NAME                             |
+-------------------+----------------------------------+
|                 1 | Leather seats                    |
|                 1 | Electronic stability control     |
|                 2 | Power steering                   |
|                 4 | ABS                              |
|                 4 | Airbag                           |
|                 4 | Cruise control                   |
|                 5 | Leather seats                    |
|                 5 | Electronic stability control     |
+-------------------+----------------------------------+
```

A criteria like this:

```
criteria.setVehicleName="Toyota Auris";

new GenericVehicleAccessory tmp0 = new GenericVehicleAccessory();
tmp0.setName="Leather Seats";
new GenericVehicleAccessory tmp1 = new GenericVehicleAccessory();
tmp1.setName="Electronic stability control";
criteria.addToAccessory(tmp0);
criteria.addToAccessory(tmp1);
```

would select the GenericVehicle entity with ID=1 (since ID=5 not have Electronic Stability Control).

How can I do that by using JPA Criteria API?

Comment: possible duplicate of [JPA: Find all articles that have a common set of tags](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21644726/jpa-find-all-articles-that-have-a-common-set-of-tags)

Comment: I don't think that is the same, since I am required to do it by using Criteria API. Thanks anyway.

Comment: Well, translate the JPQL query to Criteria. Not sure what you'll gain except unreadable code though.

Comment: I know how to do it in sql and in jpql, but not how to do it by using the Criteria API. The reason I don't want to use jpql is I am working with dynamic queries and have a lots of predicates which I would like to use. But if you know how to use JPQL together with Criteria API I can take it as a solution =)