# spring data jpa and condition for multiple collection

Tags: java, spring, postgresql, jpa, spring-data-jpa

i want to pass a list in which all should match.

```
  @Query("select g.name as name FROM Gym  g  " +
            "LEFT JOIN g.listOfEquipment   listOfEquipment  " +
            "WHERE " +
            "(((:listOfEquipment) is null) or listOfEquipment.id in (:listOfEquipment)) "+
            "AND (((:listOfAmenity) is null) or listOfAmenity.id in (:listOfAmenity))")
  Page<Map<String, Object>> listing(@Param("listOfEquipment") Set<Integer> listOfEquipment,@Param("listOfAmenity") Set<Integer> listOfAmenity)
```

above query working for `OR` but i need `AND`

suppose i am passing `1,2,3`
then result should be all `gym` who has equipment `1 and 2 and 3`
same for amenity also

i tried 
[Finding items with a set containing all elements of a given set with jpql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14340156/finding-items-with-a-set-containing-all-elements-of-a-given-set-with-jpql)

but its not helping me becuase there are multiple filters

url is

```
http://localhost:8080/filter?listOfEquipment=5,3&listOfAmenity=51,13&sort=name
```

Comment: "not working". I wonder what that means. Perhaps by looking at the invoked SQL you would find more? Nobody here sees what the entity classes are either

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This query should give you the `Gym.id`s matching all the `listOfEquipment`s assuming the list doesn't contain duplicates.

```
select g.id as name 
FROM Gym  g 
LEFT JOIN g.listOfEquipment listOfEquipment
WHERE listOfEquipment.id in (:listOfEquipment)) 
GROUP BY g.id
HAVING count(g.id) = #{#listOfEquipment.size}
```

You can use it and a similar query for the `listOfAmenity` as subselects in your main query.

```
select g.name as name 
FROM Gym  g 
LEFT JOIN g.listOfEquipment listOfEquipment 
WHERE (((:listOfEquipment) is null) 
    OR g.id in (
    select g.id as name 
    FROM Gym  g 
    LEFT JOIN g.listOfEquipment listOfEquipment
    WHERE listOfEquipment.id in (:listOfEquipment)) 
    GROUP BY g.id
    HAVING count(g.id) = #{#listOfEquipment.size}   
)) 
AND (((:listOfAmenity) is null) 
    OR g.id in (
    select g.id as name 
    FROM Gym  g 
    LEFT JOIN g.listOfAmenity listOfAmenity
    WHERE listOfAmenity.id in (:listOfAmenity)) 
    GROUP BY g.id
    HAVING count(g.id) = #{#listOfAmenity.size}   
))
```

Answer (score 1):

there is a missing bracket in the last AND condition 
it should be as following

```
@Query("select g.name as name FROM Gym  g  " +
        "LEFT JOIN g.listOfEquipment   listOfEquipment  " +
        "WHERE " +
        "(((:listOfEquipment) is null) or listOfEquipment.id in        (:listOfEquipment)) "+
        "AND (((:listOfAmenity) is null) or listOfAmenity.id in (:listOfAmenity))")
```

Comment: may be missing because that's not my original query.
but its not solving my problem.
because i don't want `or` condition i need `and` condition