# Select rows having ALL of the IN list references

Tags: java, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I have these models and repository:

(skipping all unrelated fields and getters/setters)

```
public class Contact {

    @Id
    private Integer id;

    private String name;

    @ManyToMany
    private List<TargetGroup> targetGroups = new ArrayList<>();

}
```

```
public class TargetGroup {

    @Id
    private Integer id;

    @NotBlank
    private String name;

}
```

```
@Repository
public interface ContactRepository extends CrudRepository<Contact, Integer> {

    @Query("SELECT c FROM Contact c JOIN c.targetGroups tg " +
            "WHERE (tg.id IN :targetGroups)")
    Page<ContactView> customFilterWithTargetGroups(@Param("targetGroups") Set<Integer> targetGroups, Pageable pageable);

}
```

In short, `customFilterWithTargetGroups` method returns contacts having one of provided target group ids. This works fine.

Now I need to select contacts that have ALL of the provided target group ids. It is possible with JPA?

All I can think of is constructing query manually as a string and then executing it with entity manager, but that presents myriad of other problems (paging, sorting, projection and all those goodies that JPA repository does for you). And I don't know how to do it anyway :-)

So I wonder if there is maybe a simple solution for that.

Comment: can you show Contact and targetGroups class

Comment: Perhaps `@Query("SELECT c FROM Contact c WHERE c.targetGroups.id IS NOT NULL")`

Comment: I think what you're looking for is `JpaSpecificationExecutor`. You'd add it to your interface such as `public interface ContactRepository extends CrudRepository<Contact, Integer>, JpaSpecificationExecutor<Contact>`, but thats all I can provide as I have not used that before: Look here for more example: https://javadeveloperzone.com/spring/spring-jpa-dynamic-query-example/

Comment: Are those the droids you're looking for? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14340156/finding-items-with-a-set-containing-all-elements-of-a-given-set-with-jpql

Comment: @Thomas yup, that looks exactly like what I am looking for. Thank you a million times!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the end, as kindly pointed out by **@Thomas**, there was already solution for my problem here - [Finding items with a set containing all elements of a given set with jpql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14340156/finding-items-with-a-set-containing-all-elements-of-a-given-set-with-jpql)

I decided to share exact solution code for my problem here, maybe it will help somebody:

```
@Query("SELECT c FROM Contact c JOIN c.targetGroups tg " +
            "WHERE (tg.id IN :targetGroups)" +
            " GROUP BY c.id HAVING count(c.id) = :groupsCount")
    Page<ContactView> customFilterWithTargetGroups (@Param("targetGroups") Set<Integer> targetGroups, @Param("groupsCount") long groupsCount, Pageable pageable);
```