# How create JPA criteria query to match every item in given collection against an ElementCollection

Tags: jpa, criteria-api

First I created a generic predicate that tries to find any matche in an element collection. E.g. for an Entity:

```
@Entity
public class Movie {
...
    @ElementCollection
    private Set<String> genre;
...
}
```

The predicate will match for given collection containing ["action", "drama"] all movies with "action" OR "drama" in their genre collection.

The predicate is looking this (generic):

```
public static <E> Predicate matchStringSetCaseInsensitive(Set<String> set, SetAttribute<E, String> attribute,
        CriteriaBuilder criteriaBuilder, Root<E> root, boolean isStrict) {
    Predicate predicate;
    if (!isEmpty(set)) {
        List<Predicate> matchEach = new ArrayList<>();
        Join<E, String> joinedString = root.join(attribute,JoinType.LEFT);
        for (String string : set) {
            matchEach.add(criteriaBuilder.equal(criteriaBuilder.lower(joinedString), string.toLowerCase()));
        }
        if (isStrict) {
            //NOT working 
            predicate = criteriaBuilder.and(matchEach.toArray(new Predicate[] {}));
        } else {
            predicate = criteriaBuilder.or(matchEach.toArray(new Predicate[] {}));
        }
    } else {
        predicate = criteriaBuilder.isEmpty(root.get(attribute));
    }
    return predicate;
}
```

**isStrict is set to false** in the described case.

The problem is, it is not working with `isStrict = true`. With true the query tries to find entries with a genre matching all given genres - this obviously can't work. Given "action", "drama" it matches entries with genre that are equal to "action" AND "drama".

How make this work? I thought about somehow using the or and counting distinct results:

- `isStrict = true` means givenset.size = count of some substring
- `isStrict = false` means 1<= count of some substring

Can someone give advice to create an Predicate matching every given item in set against the ElementCollection in target Entity?

Answer (score 1):

I managed to create a separate predicate to match all elements in given set:

```
public static <E> Predicate matchStringSetContainsAll(Set<String> set, SetAttribute<E, String> attribute,
            CriteriaBuilder cB, Root<E> root, CriteriaQuery<E> query, boolean strict) {
        Predicate predicate;

        if (!isEmpty(set)) {
            Subquery<Long> subquery = query.subquery(Long.class);
            Root<E> subQueryRoot = subquery.correlate(root);

            SetJoin<E, String> tagJoin = subQueryRoot.join(attribute);
            Predicate[] match = set.stream().map(tag -> cB.equal(cB.lower(tagJoin), tag.toLowerCase()))
                    .toArray(Predicate[]::new);
            Predicate tagMatch = cB.or(match);

            subquery.select(cB.count(tagJoin)).where(tagMatch);
            Predicate matchAll = cB.equal(subquery, set.size());
            Predicate strictP = cB.and();
            if (strict) {
                Subquery<Long> countAll = query.subquery(Long.class);
                Root<E> countAllRoot = countAll.correlate(root);
                SetJoin<E, String> join = countAllRoot.join(attribute);
                countAll.select(cB.count(join));
                strictP = cB.equal(countAll, set.size());
            }
            predicate = cB.and(matchAll, strictP);
        } else {
            predicate = cB.isEmpty(root.get(attribute));
        }

        return predicate;
    }
```

If `strict==true` it will only match if the target attribute does not have more entries than the given.

The approach is to use count in a sub select as suggested here:
[Finding items with a set containing all elements of a given set with jpql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14340156/finding-items-with-a-set-containing-all-elements-of-a-given-set-with-jpql)

(the second answer tith double negated `in` is not working)