# Selecting where an entity contains a list which elements are not in another list

Tags: jpa, jpql

My question is based on this other question: [Selecting where an entity contains a list thats a subset of another list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4638543/selecting-where-an-entity-contains-a-list-thats-a-subset-of-another-list)

But what I want to do is this:

I am writing a JPQL query and i have the following scenario. I have a Question entity which contains a list of Tags. I would like to select all Questions that **do not contains any** given tag in a List. How do i do this with JPA?

I would like to do something like SELECT x FROM Question x WHERE x.tags 'do not contains any' :tags

I tried to use 'NOT IN', but it not work. In this case, it's returned all Question with at least on tag not in the 'tags' list. I want to return only the Question with all the tags not in the 'tags' list.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try a sub select that finds the employee with a project in the list, then use not exists in the main query.  Something like

```
SELECT x FROM Question x WHERE not exists( select tag from x.tags tag where tag in  :tags )
```