# JPA Query: List of enums IN list of enums

Tags: java, jpa, enums

I have a search criteria object which contains a list of enums.

The search result also has a list of enums.

I want to be able to find search results that contain all of the enums listed in the search criteria.

I have tried the following but get an

> IllegalArugmentException the parameter value [ENUM_VALUE_X] did
>   not match the expected type java.util.Collection (n/a)

I feel like I'm making a silly mistake somewhere but can't figure out what it is. What am I doing wrong?

```
String queryStr = "select distinct result from SearchResult result where 
result.enumsList IN :enumsList"
...
Query query = entityManager.createQuery(queryStr, SearchResult.class);
query.setParameter("enumsList", criteria.getEnumsList());
//criteria.getEnumsList() = [ENUM_VALUE_X, ENUM_VALUE_Y]
```

Comment: since the IN operator is for a single value IN a multiple value then it is clearly invalid syntax. Any JPA doc would tell you this

Comment: Please show us SearchResult entity.

Comment: @BillyFrost That's what I was thinking. But is there no way to check a list IN list without checking each element in the list separately?

Comment: @wypieprz It's a huge file. Is there some specific part/reason you wanted to see it?

Comment: I can guess there is something like `Collection<EnumValue> enumsList` for which JPQL will not work as mentioned by Billy Frost. A workaround would be either to build a dynamic query where elements are added one after another or maybe redesign the entity model a little (e.g. Map<K,V> works with the `IN` expression so using such a map where K acts as enum type and V acts as its description would do the trick).

Comment: @wypieprz Yes, there is a list of enums in the entity, as I've mentioned in the post. Will take your suggestions into consideration. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a rather ugly approach to solve this (although it works 100%):

```
List<SomeEnum> enumList = criteria.getEnumsList();
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
for (int i = 0; i < enumList.size(); i++) {
    if (i == 0) {
        sb.append("WHERE :e").append(i).append(" MEMBER OF result.enumsList");
    } else {
        sb.append(" AND ").append(":e").append(i).append(" MEMBER OF result.enumsList");
    }
}
Query query = em.createQuery("SELECT DISTINCT result FROM SearchResult result "+ sb.toString(), SearchResult.class);
for (int i = 0; i < enumList.size(); i++) {
    query.setParameter("e" + i, enumList.get(i));
}
List<SearchResult> resultList = query.getResultList();
```

---

Here is a suggestion of [zyexal](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21742896/5909679), which works as well, although it matches one occurance and checks the length of the list. So exception of the delimiter is possible:

```
Query query = em.createQuery("SELECT DISTINCT result FROM SearchResult result JOIN result.enumsList e WHERE e IN :enums GROUP BY result HAVING COUNT(distinct e) = :enumsSize", SearchResult.class);
query.setParameter("enums", criteria.getEnumsList());
query.setParameter("enumsSize", criteria.getEnumsList().size());
List<SearchResult> resultList = query.getResultList();
```